# test for moderation in a quadratic regression model

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, interaction, stata, polynomial

I am trying to test for moderation in a quadratic regression model. my results show significant evidence of a quadratic relationship on one of the independent variables (x1) and also significant evidence that the interactions between the linear and quadratic components of x1 and another independent  variable x2 are significant.
I am however not clear on how to show evidence of moderation by x2 on the relationship between x1 and y.

I have tried to run the regression at different levels of x2(one standard deviation above the mean and below the mean but the resulting regression results have not been significant).

Y=  β1+ β2 x1 + β3 x1^2 + β4 x2 + β5 (x1)(x2) + β6 (x1^2).(x2)

Comment: Have you visually inspected a 3D scatterplot of the data, or considered making a 3D surface fit?